# Dispor produtos da base de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, e-commerce

Neccessito de ajuda pois necessito de dispor os produtos que tenho na minha base de dados na página dos produtos.

Segue uma imagem para demonstar onde quero inserir 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que já tentaste? Essa imagem é só a imagem? Ou html que já tens feito?

Comment: é so uma imagem. Não tentei porque não sei se é para por num array e depois por no sitio das imagens ou se há uma forma melhor de fazer e é nisso que necessito de ajuda

Comment: Eu sugeria que começasses por tentar fazer um HTML e CSS que fosse parecido com a imagem final, antes mesmo de fazeres PHP (presumo que seja), quando estiveres contente com o aspecto, começas a trabalhar o PHP para ir buscar os produtos e fazer a lista de produtos dinâmica. Passos pequenos.

Comment: mas esse já é o meu design já esta tudo so falta o php mesmo

Comment: Sim, eu percebi que esse é o design que queres fazer.

Comment: o design já está feito, só falta por o php para as imagens e preço

Comment: Se já tens HTML e CSS, segue a sugestão do @I_like_trains, é por esse caminho que tens de seguir.

Comment: ae um bom carrinho para o começo http://www.davidchc.com.br/tutoriais/php-tutoriais/adicionar-opcoes-dos-produtos-ao-carrinho-de-compra-com-php/ da uma olhada la e começa a implantar se gostar ;P

Comment: @Willian isso é carrinho que é uma coisa totalmente diferente e será para fazer mais à frente, mas obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: "o design já está feito, só falta por o php para as imagens e preço" cara la tem a parte completa de vitrine/carrinho um ta ligado ao outro!

Answer (score 1):

Você deve fazer assim

```
<?php
$db=mysqli_connect(bla, bla, bla, bla); //Campos da ligação
$query=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tabela"); //Caso use mysqli
while($mostra=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ //Caso use mysqli
?>
<img src="src da pasta da imagem/<?=$mostra['imagem']; ?>" />
<span><?=$mostra['nome']; ?></span>
<?php
}
?>
```

COm isto tem os essenciais e você terá de fazer o css como desejar.

Comment: sim , mas não há uma forma de serem logo todos os itens e não só um de cada vez?

Comment: Mas ele assim irá mostrar todos, não um de cada vez. Ele tem é de ter um loop para ver quantos há e quais mostrar

Answer (score 0):

Eu sugeria que começasses por tentar fazer um HTML e CSS que fosse parecido com a imagem final, antes mesmo de fazeres PHP (presumo que seja), quando estiveres contente com o aspecto, começas a trabalhar o PHP para ir buscar os produtos e fazer a lista dinâmica. Passos pequenos.

Ao fazeres o HTML primeiro estás a definir a tua estrutura do documento, ficando mais simples depois fazer o PHP para tornar certas partes desse documento dinâmicas, com dados vindos da base de dados.

Sugeria mesmo que tentasses isto, e fosses colocando aqui problemas que vais encontrando, se não experimentaste algo ainda, provavelmente a ajuda que te vamos dar ainda te vai confundir mais ou não vai ser o melhor exercício para aprenderes o que fazer da próxima vez.

Algo que eu fazia quando estava a aprender era copiar o HTML e CSS de outros sites e perceber porque estava feito da forma que estava.

Comment: Uma pergunta com uma imagem do objectivo final, a perguntar como listar os produtos, sem qualquer código a ser mostrado, leva-me a crer que nada ainda está feito, só uma imagem. Se para passar de uma imagem para algo que funciona não são, por alto, estes passos, não sei então o que é. Se o voto negativo é por não fazer o trabalho que outra pessoa tem de fazer, então algo vai muito mal nesta comunidade.

Comment: Você tem toda a razão. Mostrar apenas a imagem e pedir que todos façam o resto pode dar razão para o fechamento da pergunta.

Comment: Sim. Eu preferia que a pergunta tivesse mais informação do que está ou não feito, e em que passo se está a ter problemas, assim podemos ajudar, que eu acho que todos aqui gostamos de fazer. A tua resposta de facto responde ao título da pergunta, mas o texto da pergunta devia ter mais informação, até mesmo para poderes adaptar a tua resposta para ser mais focada para o caso dele.

Comment: Eu dei-te +1 para reparar os danos que ele fez e já sinalizei a pergunta como não clara o suficiente

Comment: Eu percebi que tinha sido isso, obrigado :)